# PyCharm - Autoimport not showing virtualenv packages

Tags: python, pycharm, virtualenv

PyCharm interpreter is recognizing my packages from venv:

[image]

(Django is installed in my virtual environment).

I am even allowed to navigate through it (ctrl+click):

[image]

But the imports are broken! When I try to auto import classes that are recognized by the interpreter, they don't appear as an auto-import option if they are inside my virtualenv:

[image]

I mean, if I manually import that class, the interpreter will recognize it, but the autoimport won't show it as an option. What's happening?

Also, my python interpreter is properly configured:

[image]

This is Ubuntu 22.04.1 and PyCharm 2022.2.3

Answer (score 2):

try to mark your virtualenv folder as excluded

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/configuring-project-structure.html

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34434387)